# Can I read/write from the same buffer while also using a triple frame buffer?

Tags: video, framebuffer, xilinx, dma, read-write

I have to build a Video Direct Memory Access (VDMA) that reads and writes 4k resolution video to and from DDR3. I want to use triple frame buffering (client's specs) but I also want to be able to read the data from the same buffer as they are being written (with a specific delay due to different read/write frequencies). From my understanding a triple frame buffer on most standard IPs (like the Xilinx AXI Vdma Core IP) "locks" each buffer for one specific function and uses the third spare buffer to switch functions in case they are not synchronized. But how can I "unlock" that to be able to read the same buffer as it is being written?

Answer (score 3):

You should look at the genlock options of the VDMA core, it will allow you to do exactly what you want. However, this is a very bad idea.

First, even if you read the same frame that is written, you will likely read invalid pixels if your read is faster than the video (which it should). There is no way to stop the VDMA read so that it doesn't catch up to the write, synchronization is done frame-wise, no synchronization within frame. Note that AXI default behavior is to give higher priority to read access.

Second, you really shouldn't need to. Simply store the input video in a FIFO to cross clock domains, at the same time as you send it to the VDMA framebuffer. As long as your read function is fast enough and that the FIFO has sufficient size, you will save precious memory bandwidth/power.

Don't forget that a 4k 30fps stream at 4:2:2 sampling requires 4 Gbits/s memory bandwidth. If you write it once and read it twice, as you suggest, you need 12 Gbits/s effective memory bandwidth, which is starting to be a lot. Should your 4k stream uses 4:4:4 or 60fps, you need a lot more memory bandwidth.

You should really try to prevent memory write/read. If you need to read the incomming video stream (at a different frequency) as you write it to the framebuffer, do everything you can to prevent another memory read and use FIFOs instead.

Comment: Thanks for the info.
 I have to use 4K stream. I have no bandwidth issue, my #1 requirement is to maximize stream quality and minimize latency.I have a 4x10 GB-ethernet input. Read is twice as fast (120 Hz vs 60Hz) but it will read from two write functions.

Could you elaborate on the FIFO use? What do you mean by "cross clock domains"? Do you suggest writing to both the DDR and a FIFO and having the read function use the FIFO rather than the memory?

Also I will probably have to design the Core myself as the standard IPs cannot help me with frame cropping which is also a requirement.